# Attempting to use OpenCV 2.4 C++ library when .so files installed in a non-standard location

Tags: c++, opencv, g++

I've read some other posts about doing something similar to this, and I know about the existence of the -L and -l flags for G++, however I can't seem to get it right. All of the .so files for opencv 2.4 are currently installed in $HOME/.local/lib, since this is a VM I do not have root access to, and cannot get the administrator to install openCV. I am trying to compile a project with

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

at the top. Here are a few of the things I have tried:

g++ -L$HOME/.local/lib -lopencv OpenCVTest.cpp

g++ -L$HOME/.local/lib OpenCVTest.cpp

g++ -I$HOME/.local/lib OpenCVTest.cpp

I have tried changing to:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

and then running:
g++ -L$HOME/.local/lib -lopencvcore OpenCVTest.cpp

Whichever of these I run, I get the error:

> OpenCVTest.cpp:1:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory

When I used opencv/core/core.hpp, it had the same error but with that instead.

$HOME does not expand to a path with spaces in it, and it works the same way when I write out the entire path instead of using $HOME.

What am I getting wrong? Are the names after -l not correct? Where do I find the correct names? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hard to say with certainty what you are doing wrong without more information on what is going wrong. If you get error messages, paste them into the question. Also make sure `$HOME` doesn't expand to a string with spaces in it.

Comment: Groovy. Thanks. The `-I` needs to direct the compiler to the location of the include files, not the library files . `-I<path to OpenCV include directory>` Something like `g++ -I$HOME/.local/include  -L$HOME/.local/lib -lopencv OpenCVTest.cpp`

Comment: I tried that and now it only fails to compile because I'm a bad C++ dev, thanks!

Comment: Rough language, C++. One of the toughest out there that actually sees use outside of a research lab or a joke, and the only things you can do to get better at it are a lot of reading and a lot of practice.

Comment: Had one more issue but after changing $LD_LIBRARY_PATH it's all working smoothly, thanks for the help!

Comment: The library files are sometimes just little stubs that tell the program to load the real library at runtime and don't actually contain any of the executable code. And you just figured that out.

Comment: An alternative that makes for a larger program (sometimes MUCH larger) but doesn't require the extra library files when you distribute it is static linking. The libraries get built into the program.

Comment: Is there a good reason to do static linking other than avoiding having to set an environment variable (that is assuming I don't have to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with it)?

Comment: Whether static linking is a benefit is often a coin-toss. I brought it up so that you'll know the option is out there. Sometimes you have to do it and sometimes you'd be stupid to do it, and the rest of the times in the middle do whatever looks like it'll cause the fewest problems going forward.

Comment: Alright then, I'll stick to dynamic linking for now since I know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question resolved in comments, the command that successfully compiles my project is:

g++ -I$HOME/.local/include -L$HOME/.local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -lrt -lpthread -lm -ldl OpenCVTest.cpp -o OpenCVTest

and to run ./OpenCVTest successfully, I had to call:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/.local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH